# SoundEngine click sound

Tags: audio

I am using SoundEngine from CrashLanding to play some sounds.

each sound has 1 second and is to be played when a button is clicked.

If you click the button just one, everything is fine. But if you click the button a second time while the first sound is already playing you hear a click sound.

How to solve that?

I saw apple pulled CrashLanding from their site. I read that they considered SoundEngine to be unstable under some conditions.

Anyway it is working fine for me, except for this annoying click sound.

Is there any way to solve that? BTW, what is the alternative to SoundEngine for using OpenAL?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with SoundEngine exactly, but some general advice can help here. I suspect it's an issue to play same sound from same buffer, cos SoundEngine could rewind it back to start without turning it off - hence the "click" sound.

1. Stop the sound before you start playing it again.
2. Use different playback buffer for different sound instances.